# How do you convert CSV data to .md files via python and modify a specific column in the process?

Tags: python, csv, markdown

I have a big .csv file with data of movies which I'm trying to modify via python.

The script I got to generate the .md files works fine but the 9th column is Genres and it is formatted like:

```
Genres: "Comedy, Action, Thriller"
```

The output I am generating in .md needs to be:

```
Genres:
- Comedy
- Action
- Thriller
```

I have a second script to clean the .csv file before generating the .md so I thought to replace the comma into a newline with a hyphen like this:

```py
import csv

input_file = open('movies.csv', 'r')
output_file = open('output.csv', 'w+', newline='')

reader = csv.reader(input_file, quotechar='"')
writer = csv.writer(output_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, delimiter=';')
for line in reader:
    line[8] = line[8].replace('","', '\n -')
    writer.writerow(line)
```

I'm not very experienced in python so I am getting this error when running the script.

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct approach, as it might be possible to replace the column formatting in the same script that produces the .md files.

Any tips on how to solve this?

Comment: In your CSV file there are probably some rows without 9 columns.

Comment: All empty fields are filled with "N/A" in this case.